# Could any one please help me how should i create a contact-us form in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, contact-form

I am using Oform to create contact-us form in Orchard. 
But it is not working properly.  I refered "http://extendorchard.co.uk/tutorial-oforms" and done the same. 
But now i am getting error

**Serial number needed!  Invalidated oForms install is a fully functional Orchard module which has No limitations. However for a small fee you can remove this text and the link on the front end, and HELP us to continue the development and support of this module. Please click here to get the serial number: http://extendorchard.co.uk/license-oforms.**

Comment: Have you carefully read and understood the error message?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use oForms to create a contact form. This post gives you a step by step walkthrough on how to build a contact form using just the built-in features of Orchard.

https://web.archive.org/web/20170604194143/http://devdirective.com:80/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha

Comment: I created a content type but for name and email fields i am not getting "Input" field type could you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Hi I creted Contact Form but still getting below error:Cannot create content. Anonymous users do not have Submit_ContactUsForm permission.

Comment: @user2458607 The post that Bertrand provided has a section about permissions - follow those instructions and you should be fine.

Comment: **BROKEN LINK**

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I replaced the link with a Wayback Machine version. Sorry I don't have time right now to expand a full answer, hopefully this unblocks you.